# UK based, new US employer changed contract on first day. How to handle professionally?

Tags: software-industry, united-states, contracts, united-kingdom

I was offered a job by a US software company.
On my first day at work they told me they couldn't actually hire me for legal and technical reasons.

So, now they want me to be a consultant and to become self-employed.

I had plans to buy a house in UK soon, and now I won't be able to do it unless I provide at least 24 months of invoices as self-employed.

Nobody is taking responsibility, they are blaming their 'solicitors'.

Therefore, my question is: how can I handle this situation (sudden request to change contract) in a professional way?

Comment: "now I won't be able to do it unless I provide 24-36 months of invoices as self-employed" - is that based on what you've read, or have you actually verified that with the bank? I'd imagine you could convince them of your earning power from your old pay slips and that your situation is stable with whatever documentation from the new company, but I don't know what level of assurance they need.

Comment: Did the signed contract allow them to do that?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39402/discussion-on-question-by-ta-bamboo-uk-based-new-us-employer-changed-contract-o).

Comment: I wonder if the "extra costs" they're trying to avoid here are things like paid time off and public holidays, tax and national insurance contributions, and other benefits. A generous package may not turn out to be really very generous at all if it doesn't include those kinds of things.

Comment: In the U.S it's easy for a company to lay-off an employee for no reason, but the U.K has certain laws in place that don't allow them to do that; the OP should be covered under these laws and I do wonder whether the U.S company is aware of that.

Comment: Please, hint or identify this company. People should stay away from it based on your experience!

Comment: Note: if you do start working as a contractor (self employed) you will need to be charging 30-50% more, just to cover the costs and risk associated with that type of employment. (Which would still be better then 2x for the US company)

Comment: @TCSGrad That could be a 'Career limiting move'

Comment: The fact that they think it's going to cost them more than they expected almost certainly implies they think UK jurisdiction is relevant here. Work to the original signed contract, to the letter. If they don't pay you it's [constructive dismissal](https://www.gov.uk/dismissal/unfair-and-constructive-dismissal) plain and simple.(You can still look for other jobs in the background and resign, but seek professional advice).

Comment: Does the original contract specify how long it is in effect or give requirements for amount of time for notice on their part? If not, they might conceivably be able to weasel out as, "yes, we signed the contract, then we fired him the first day". Otherwise, "I discovered I couldn't afford it" is not a valid reason to terminate a contract. That's why people sign contracts: so the other party is committed even if they later decide it's not working out as they hoped.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Let's think about this:

**Either the company was shockingly incompetent in hiring you or intentionally misleading**.  Despite having accountants, solicitors, and an HR department, they apparently did not figure out the cost of employing you before offering you a written contract?  That is quite a mistake to make, but I suppose it is possible.  A more worrying possibility is that this was a bait-and-switch, and they never intended to hire you on the basis of the original contract.  Ultimately, you can't know which of these is true, but it doesn't reflect well on the company either way.

**Their response after making a mistake has been combative.**  I would expect a mistake of this magnitude to be followed by a much more conciliatory response.  Some of the problems I see:

- **They refused to just take the financial hit and hire you anyway.**  A company that values its employees should just bear this cost, as it was their mistake, rather than trying to back out of a signed contract--unless they legitimately can't afford to pay. But being unable to afford one extra year of your salary is hard to believe: they seem like a pretty good sized organization, based on your description of the situation, and surely your salary is not *that* big!
- **They are tone-deaf to your situation.** Insisting they are being "generous", after they just messed up in a way that will clearly cost you big time, is quite worrying.  They ought to be apologetic, but instead they are trying claim your unhappiness with their huge mistake is your problem!
- **They are nickel-and-diming you** by not being flexible at all on covering your extra expenses.
- **They have no problem turning up the pressure in contract negotiations**, treating you as an adversary rather than a new team member that they value.  Adding a new clause about suing you seems like a pressure tactic.  The refusal to add any protections is worrying.

All in all, this adds up to a situation in which **I would be worried about my future working for this company, no matter how these negotiations turn out.**  Therefore I would take a less "friendly" approach to the negotiations.  Two options I see:

**Fight for the original contract, contacting a solicitor to assess your options.**  I'm not qualified to give legal advice. But it seems quite possible that what they are doing is not legal.

- They may be failing to honor the contract (even if there is a probationary period where they can swiftly terminate you, they appear to have been acting in bad faith).  I don't know the right technical terms for this, but I would be surprised if there was no basis for challenging this in UK employment law.
- They also appear to be pushing [to classify you (wrongly) as self-employed](https://www.gov.uk/employment-status/selfemployed-contractor).  This is not just something that can be designated arbitrarily.  You have to actually *function as self-employed* to be classified this way.

It's possible that raising the illegality of their actions might convince them to retreat and offer the original contract.  Or, in the event that things can't be worked out, you may be able to take them to court and collect damages (whether the size of the damages would be worth the hassle is not something I can answer).

Another option is to **go the self-employed route, but insist on being *really* self-employed**.  State that if you are going to be self-employed, you want to send them a quote for the agreed work, with a price that you set, and that they can negotiate from that as a starting point.  Also, if you are self employed you need freedom to do the work when and where you please, and take other clients.  You can point out that UK tax law requires this sort of thing--these aren't unreasonable demands you are making.  This will give you more freedom to seek other opportunities.  It will also give you more control of the situation, making it harder for them to further take advantage of you in the future.

**Both of these options carry some risk.** If you really feel you can't walk away from this job, it limits your negotiating options, but the second one is less risky, and you can do that one more mildly if you choose (the first option is pretty much all-or-nothing).

Comment: Not sure how it works in UK, but in several countries self-employment has a few conditions, including  having **more than** a single client, because that qualifies instantly as disguised employment.

Comment: [IR35](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IR35) outlines what it means to be 'self employed' in the UK. Practically speaking - "if it looks like a duck, and quacks like a duck" - if you're acting as if you're an employee, you are legally speaking, and employee. How this works over international boundaries though, is "complicated".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39577/discussion-on-answer-by-dan1111-uk-based-new-us-employer-changed-contract-on-fi).

Answer (score 86):

Tell them that **this is not what you signed up for**. They have gone back on your agreement and violated your contract, before you've even started work. Say **you regretfully must decline to work with them**.

And when they come back at you with nonsense about how you've signed a contract, remind them what that contract says. No court is going to side with them defending a contract that you're walking away from *because they have completely broken it already*.

Any further discussion takes place through your lawyer, *only*.

In the meantime, **call up your old supervisor, tell him it didn't work out, and ask whether there is room for you to return**. It hasn't been very long, so that may very well be possible. It might sound strange but **there's really no shame** in simply returning to your job. I work with three people who have gone off and varyingly worked for other companies for a bit (later realising their mistake) since they first became my colleagues.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39453/discussion-on-answer-by-lightness-races-in-orbit-uk-based-new-us-employer-chang).

Answer (score 42):

I would walk away from this US clown company and either find a serious company or get the old one back. Obviously, they treat their employees as disposable cattle and not resources and you don't want to be near anything like that. I think their "additional expenses" claim is ridiculous as they should have thought about that before. Sometimes, under the right circumstances, going back to your old company could result in an increased salary.

Please write a blurb on glassdoor.com or similar sites to warn others about this despicable company.

Answer (score 18):

I am not a lawyer. **You need a lawyer.** The legalities in the UK of unilaterally changing a contract of employment are complex. The UK is not the US, and employment is not generally "at-will".

Changing a contract you have agreed to on day one, with no notice at all, is certainly bad practice and [probably illegal in the UK](https://www.gov.uk/your-employment-contract-how-it-can-be-changed). "We didn't expect the expenses we're incurring" is surely [not a valid reason to change a contract on day 1](https://www.gov.uk/dismissal/reasons-you-can-be-dismissed) and the courts will almost certainly take a dim view of it because due diligence should have been undertaken in drawing up the contract. Unexpected expenses *may* be a valid reason to give you your contractual notice of dismissal, if there is one (the statutory notice period only [kicks in after a month](https://www.gov.uk/redundant-your-rights/notice-periods)).

You could attempt to enforce the contract you originally signed. You could accept the new contract. You could accept their abrogation of the original contract, not accept their new contract, and walk away, possibly to rejoin your previous employer. You **must** get the advice of an employment lawyer.

Answer (score 15):

> they added a new clause where the company might sue me to hell and back if they find it appropriate

That's a contract that I might be disinclined to sign.

For example as an employee I wouldn't expect to be *sued* if someone finds a fault in software that I've written (because I expect them to test it too, etc.) ... but as an contractor (perhaps a.k.a. "independent supplier") I'm not so sure. What if they were sued by *their* client, and they tried to deflect the liability onto me?

They may allow you to tweak the wording of the contract slightly (before you sign it, assuming your request is reasonable and they want to employ you).

For example I once altered a contract so that it said I could expect to be sued in the case of "gross negligence", instead of just "negligence" (I decided there's a difference between negligence and gross negligence and the latter would be more difficult to prove).

If you are going to be self-employed, here's quite an interesting video I watched recently on the subject of legalities -- [Mike Monteiro: F*ck You, Pay Me](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jVkLVRt6c1U)

Comment: Re: "For example I once altered a contract so that it said I could expect to be sued in the case of 'gross negligence', instead of just 'negligence' (I decided there's a difference between negligence and gross negligence and the latter would be more difficult to prove)": That sounds like the sort of thing you should get legal advice about (unless you're already legally qualified). Your supposition sounds commonsensical, but the law is not entirely (or even mostly) about common sense.

Comment: My point was that small changes in the wording of the contract might make a big difference; also that their lawyer's job is to draft a contract which favours *them*, and that the contract is negotiable before you sign it but not afterwards. If for example the contract says you have to give them a pony, and if they blame their lawyer for that clause, you can tell them you're willing to sign the contract if (but only if) that clause is removed.

Comment: I understood your point, and I don't disagree with it, but I *do* disagree with the lack of a big "you should discuss this BS with your lawyer first". :-P

Comment: That's the subject/substance of the video recommended in the last paragraph.

Comment: The clause is probably an attempt to turn the questioner into a genuine contractor and not a disguised employee who's going to run foul of IR35. If your limited company is responsible for the quality of what you do, then that's taken as an indication that you really are selling a service and not just evading tax and/or NICs on employment income.

Comment: "Negligence" is something that you do all the time when you are not behaving absolutely perfectly. "Gross negligence" is something that would be really badly wrong.

Answer (score 11):

You can start your one-man limited liability company in the UK and use it to maximise your income by being tax-efficient.

Instead of a monthly salary, you would agree on a daily rate. I'd say that £100 gross daily rate (that is you pay all your cost, taxes, etc out of that rate) is equivalent to about £15,000 annual pre-tax income (your official income where the employee withholds tax and employee's national insurance).

Any threats of suing you are void, as long as you make sure any contract is between them and your limited liability company, and that there is no money in the company by paying out everything as dividends. Which is not optimal for tax purposes, but what can you do.

BTW. No need to handle this professionally. You need to handle this in the way that is most beneficial to you.

Comment: Be careful you can get caught for disguised employment under IR35

Comment: I don't think the disguised employee will be the one in trouble if they are caught.

Comment: @dyesdyes I wouldn't be too sure about that.

Comment: IR35 is hard if you have a contract that makes you liable for all kinds of things.

Comment: @dyesdyes IR35 would definitely apply if the OP has only one client and works full time for that client - and that would have a significant tax impact. The hiring company may also be affected but who cares...

Comment: HMRC is busy with greedy contractors who declared their payments as "loans" to avoid paying any tax.

Comment: @assylias IR35 is a LOT more complicated than that.

Comment: @dyesdyes You are wrong. The "disguised employee" is liable for IR35. Basically it's the NI contributions you'd have to make (around 20% although it's most complex than that since there's tax free allowances etc) for the duration of the employment + potentially up to 30% of that extra as penalties if they decide you didn't have a case. For any decent length contract potentail IR35 liabilities are huge and they all hit the contractor since it's the contractor that the tax man thinks is avoiding the tax.

Answer (score 6):

The contract appears to be a bait-and-switch, in that they tempted you away from your previous employment with a very generous sum, only to rescind said contract after you accepted, which I believe violates good faith in terms of legality, and certainly illegal.

Now they have you in an unfavourable situation, they will attempt to whittle down and remove the benefits and hope the pressure of needing a job forces you to accept the now unfair and dubious terms.

The fact they continue to, like a classic Nigerian scam email, offer you generous sums whilst whittling down your rights (being self-employed means they can terminate you at any time, and the lawsuit clause means they can sue you like a third party: basically, they intend to get you to work for them, then sue back the 'generous' money they give you) is highly suspicious and a red flag for underhanded approaches.

This is a malicious company, and I would actually go so far as to recommend detailing your experiences online publicly and outing the company so other people do not fall for this trap. Such underhanded practices should not be tolerated nor disguised.

Answer (score 5):

As you've already pushed back on the T&Cs for the consultant role, it sounds like what you've got is pretty much their final offer, so it's now up to you to decide what you want to do. You've got three options:

- Take the consultant role, with the intention of staying in the role long-term.
- Take the consultant role, but start looking for a new role ASAP.
- Reject the consultant role.

Any of these can be handled in a professional manner: the first is easy, the last is simply "Sorry, I'm looking for a role as a permanent employee". The second is perhaps the trickiest, but so long as you do your job as well as you can for the period you're working for your employer, it's going to be "just one of those things". Your potential employer has screwed this one up *massively*, so you shouldn't be expected to go out of your way to deal with their HR mess, and you've got to earn money in the meantime.

Comment: This misses the contract has penalties / damages.   Sound like #2 is not as easy as just do your job.

Comment: You seem to be familiar with UK employment contracts.  Do you really think there is no basis to challenge the employer's actions legally?  A probation period probably exists, but the employer's actions seem borderline fraudulent (using one contract to lure someone to a job and then switching to different terms).  Of course taking legal action would ruin the relationship with the company, but if one plans to reject the role anyway, it might be worth it.

Comment: @dan1111 They're certainly incompetent. Showing that they did this maliciously or were grossly negligent (which is what you'd need to do to win a court case) would be significantly trickier, and almost certainly not worth the amount of money you'd spend on it.

Comment: @PhilipKendall that is often (usually?) true of actual legal action, but *threatening to take legal action* is much less costly and can get results.  In this case, it seems that could be done credibly.  And the company might really fear this, since they seem ignorant of the reality of doing business UK.  Not saying I'm advocating this, but...

Comment: @dan1111 it wouldnt surprise me if there was a case for constructive dismissal here - acceptance of employment offer, with the offer being substantially altered after that acceptance and a signed contract being returned.

Comment: @Paparazzi: With a limited liability company that pays all its profits out as dividends every month, there is no need to worry about damages. If they sue, and the company has no money, there's nothing they can do. That's what limited liability is there for.

Comment: @gnasher729 The question says nothing about creating an LLC.  IANAL but Limited is operable.  In the US you will leave operating money in the LLC as if you start shipping money both ways then it becomes commingling.   And you are on the hook for the maximum of your last 6 months.   And you are not protected from all breaches.  And I bet they are going to ask him to sign the contract as an individual.

Comment: @Moo it might be constructive dismissal but the remedy available might be limited when the OP hasn't yet worked for the employer for two years (it was one year until 2012 - thanks, Dave and Nick). OP needs to get legal advice.

Comment: You've got at least a couple of difficulties in UK employment law (I say, as a non-lawyer). One is whether the contract signed is actually legally possible -- they say "HR and accountants told me they couldn't actually hire me, because [it] would expose them to additional expenses". If "expenses" is setting up an EU entity to employ you, perhaps they literally *can't* employ you in the UK, and what you have isn't an employment contract yet. The other is that a UK employer can fire you for no reason up to 2 years into employment, and "expensive to keep" is better even than "no reason".

Comment: @nekomatic If the contract specifies a notice period, I don't see how they get out of paying for that, at least. I would ask at Citizens' Advice and then decide whether it's worth going legal or just walking away.

Comment: @richardb, often the notice period in the first 3 months in is 1 week in a standard UK employment contact.

Answer (score 5):

At first sight it looks like there is a good legal case against the USA Company.   However UK employment law gives very little protection to someone until they have been in a job for some time.   Assuming the notice period on the employment offer was 1 month, the most you are likely to win from the company in a legal case is 1 month’s wages.   (But you may get them to pay you 3 months wages, if they don’t wish their name to be all over the papers.)

**But trying to force a company outside of the UK to pay up, even when ordered by a UK court is expensive and likely to fail.**

Don’t sign a consultant contract with them in your personal name without getting very good legal advice!

Tell them you will need to consult with a UK lawyer on your return to the UK before you agree to anything.   Get them to pay ALL your expensive for the trip the USA cleared in your bank account, before rejecting any offer they make!

If you create a limited company in the UK, and only sign any contracts in the company name you can protect yourself from most risks of them suing you.    **To cover the costs of running the company etc, expect to get “paid” double what you would in a “job”.**

Personally I would get as much compensation out of them as possible due to them misleading you about the job and you leaving your past job, then find some other work.    **Life is too short to a setup as complex as what they are trying to get you into.**

Answer (score 2):

- I would find it hard to work for that company after these events. So forcing yourself into it should probably not be what you want.
- The issue is pretty clear; they stepped out of the contract on day 1. What does your contract say about how that works? Does it have a clause where they have to keep you on for at least XXX amount of time?
- Signed contracts cannot simple be "changed" by one party. Get a lawyer, get at least your costs back from them (that means the missed income during the time you are without job, etc.), and make perfectly clear that you will not be their victim. Depending on whether U.S. or U.K. law applies (both of which I'm not terribly familiar with) you might have more or less leverage.

Answer (score 2):

Have they increased the monetary value of their offer now they are asking you to be a contractor? Being self employed means that you lose the benefits of having an employer: you will need to pay your own employer's national insurance and you won't get holiday or sick pay, etc. etc.

As a rule of thumb, as a contractor you should be looking for roughly double the salary that you would receive as a full time employee.

Answer (score 1):

So yes, they've broken your original contract and they're trying to make things even worse by strong-arming you into a situation that adds a ton of uncertainty. The natural answer here is **sue them for lost earnings, emotional damage, etc and go back to your last employer**. But there are a couple of separate issues:

- Getting money out of them will be hard. We're talking a tribunal here and then chasing them across the planet to get that enforced in their jurisdiction. This isn't easy or cheap.
- Your old employer is under no obligation to talk to you ever again. If your leaving hurt them or there's any animosity, you can expect a demotion and a pay cut.

So by all means talk to your old employer and ask for a firm, *written* offer of employment and a lawyer **because you have been wronged**, just don't expect these to put everything right.

---

Just as a quick sidebar, there *are* significant issues when hiring somebody full time in the UK. I say that speaking as somebody who works exclusively as a self-employed contractor for small companies here. They avoid a lot of taxes and paperwork by keeping me out of their PAYE schedule. A foreign company with no other presence here has a ton of stuff to set up.

They've probably done the sums, looked at what the worst-case outcome of being sued for lost earnings from breach of contract and have worked out that it would be cheaper to take that risk and push you toward a cheaper way of working.

They've been both stupid and nasty in a small amount of time, but given the climate of zero-hours contracts, unpaid internships, etc... They're neither the nastiest or the most unfair employer in history. There might be something to salvage here.

And if you can forgive past sins/idiocy (or your old employer won't touch you) you can make this a lot more favourable by doing one simple thing:

### Get paid up front (demand an advance)

Contracts clearly mean zip for them but you can have them insure themselves against this sort of nonsense and demand as much certainty as you need **in advance**. If halfway through your "contract" they say they don't need you any more, that's A-Okay. You've already been paid.

So as a little not-too-silly, not-too-risky example, you could ask them to structure your payments as so:

```
Day 0         12 months salary
Months 1-9    Zero. Nada.
Months 10+    Normal monthly salary
```

If they stop paying you at any point, they breach, contract over, and you at least 3 months severance. I'm front-loading that by 12 months above because that's when companies are their most fickle.

If you need more certainty than that, ask but expect them to nibble this back. If they start getting stupid again, you can wave your offer of work back at them, the breached contract and tell them that if they try to pursue you, you have considerable UK and EU law on your side.

---

If buying a house is the most important thing, being employed is the most important thing here. Spend too long away from it and you'll either count as self-employed or between jobs (which can be a 6-month penalty with some lenders). Brokers can help explain your contract to banks' underwriters but you might have to put your plans on ice for a year or two.

It seems *likely* you might incur a loss of some description here, so if you do, please seek the opinion of a solicitor. I'm not a lawyer and your chances of pursuing crappy contracts internationally might be much better/cheaper than I'm saying.

Answer (score -1):

I would go the self employed route.  Keep in mind that being self-employed is far better paid than standard full-time employment (expect to double your post-tax salary).  Read up about IR35, as this will give you an idea of what you'll need to work towards as a proper limited company.  You can get a mortgage as a contractor - you're best off going through a mortgage broker specialising in contractors (I used a fantastic fee-free one who works on recommendations), as the underwriting is performed differently, and this is not typically accessible direct via the branch.

Comment: Is it "far better paid" because the pre-tax/gross income is higher, i.e. must the OP ask for a higher pay because of being (i.e. in order to be) self-employed?

Comment: This is about general self employment; it doesn't address the specific offer the OP received ("self employment" at the same rate as the previous employment contract).

Comment: In this case, the offer appears to be considerably worse than being an employee.

Comment: Being self-employed should command a completely different offer.  The OP shouldn't ask for a higher pay - he should ask for a T&M contract based on his company (which he would need to set-up) providing services to their company.

Comment: @AdCar, agreed, but what *should* happen is not what has happened. The organization is not going to happily agree to double salary for the same work, when this whole situation was precipitated by their unwillingness to pay the original salary.  As it stands, this doesn't really answer the question that was asked.

Comment: You're right, I haven't answered the original question!  Apologies - I've gone back and re-read.  To best deal with it in a professional manner - accept that someone has screwed up at the organisation and propose a counter offer.  Either a full-time salary with all the benefits of being a permanent employee on the original salary offered or a contractor, working through your own limited company, at a day rate that takes into account the reduced job security and benefits.